Weierstrass factorization Theorem with simple zeros at Gaussian Integers
I'm studying Weierstrass factorization but I'm stuck on this exercise from Gamelin that asks this: "Construct an entire function that has simple zeros at the Gaussian
integers m+ni,
−
∞
<

,

<
∞ and no other zeros." What should I do in this case considering that I have two indices m,n? Thanks.

You can just enumerate them by ${z_n}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in some convenient order.

So something similar to the construction of Weierstrass σ function?

Yes. That would be the simlest form you can obtain using Weierstrass factorization theorem.

Thank you very much
